# How to get Data By Id From Database Spring Boot Java REST API

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, web-services

I build simple REST service, I want to get data key from database based id but, when I running no result showing in postman, how can I fix it?

This is My Controller

```
    //Get Key

    @RequestMapping(path="/getkey/{company_id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    String getKey(@PathVariable int company_id) {
    String encKey = null;



    gkrepo.getKeyByCompanyid(company_id);

    return encKey;


}
```

This is My Repository

```
public interface GenerateKeyRepository extends JpaRepository<KeyEntity, Integer>
{

@Query(value= "SELECT * FROM tb_key", nativeQuery = true)
List<KeyEntity> getAll();

public void getKeyByCompanyid(Integer companyid);


}
```

Comment: Did you add @Repository annotation to your repository?

Comment: You're returning encKey which is always null.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how you can expect something to be returned from a void method. `public void getKeyByCompanyid(Integer companyid);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is the fact, that you ignore the return value of the `repository` method and return `null`.

```
@RequestMapping(path="/getkey/{company_id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    String getKey(@PathVariable int company_id) {
    String encKey = null;

    gkrepo.findOneByCompanyId(company_id);

    return encKey; //YOU RETURN NULL HERE
}
```

What you need to do is to return the key from the `KeyEntity` object.

```
@RequestMapping(path="/getkey/{company_id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    String getKey(@PathVariable int company_id) {

    return gkrepo.getKeyByCompanyid(company_id).getKey();
}
```

You also need an additional method in your `repository`.

```
public interface GenerateKeyRepository extends JpaRepository<KeyEntity, Integer> {

    @Query(value= "SELECT * FROM tb_key", nativeQuery = true)
    List<KeyEntity> getAll();

    public void findOneByCompanyId(Integer companyid);
}
```

Comment: if I want use return how can i create? I want to get just data key based id, with return encKey? 

       @GetMapping(path= "/getById/{company_id}")
  
 String getById(@RequestBody KeyEntity keyEntity, @PathVariable int company_id){
 String encKey= null;
  
  KeyEntity key = new KeyEntity();
  
  encKey= key.getKeyencrypted();
  
  gkrepo.findById(company_id);
    
  return encKey;
  
 }

Answer (score 0):

You should change the method in repository as done below. Try using this.

```
 public interface GenerateKeyRepository extends JpaRepository<KeyEntity, Integer>
 {

@Query(value= "SELECT * FROM tb_key", nativeQuery = true)
List<KeyEntity> getAll();

public KeyEntity findByCompanyId(Integer companyid);
 }
```

Comment: Why not just use the inherited `findById()` method?

Comment: Because it uses the KeyEntity id not, the CompanyId

Answer (score 0):

Your Controller Should be :

```
@RequestMapping(path="/getkey/{company_id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
String getKey(@PathVariable int company_id) {
String encKey = null;

KeyEntity keyEntity = gkrepo.getKeyByCompanyid(company_id);

return keyEntity.getKey;

}
```

Your Repository should be like:

```
public interface GenerateKeyRepository extends JpaRepository<KeyEntity, Integer>
 {

@Query(value= "SELECT * FROM tb_key", nativeQuery = true)
List<KeyEntity> getAll();

public KeyEntity findByCompanyId(Integer companyid);
 }
```

Comment: getKeyByCompanyid not available

Comment: please provide your KeyEntity Bean.

Comment: If Company id is your field in Bean then it should work fine. [https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.5.0.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html]

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change your method it as it bellow

```
public interface GenerateKeyRepository extends JpaRepository<KeyEntity, Integer>
  {

    @Query(value= "SELECT * FROM tb_key", nativeQuery = true)
    List<KeyEntity> getAll();

    public KeyEntity findByCompanyId(Integer companyid);
  }
```

if you use this code , you must change  code it as it bellow

> gkrepo.findByCompanyId
>
> instead of
>
> gkrepo.getKeyByCompanyid(company_id);

OR

```
public interface GenerateKeyRepository extends JpaRepository<KeyEntity, Integer>
 {

    @Query(value= "SELECT * FROM tb_key", nativeQuery = true)
    List<KeyEntity> getAll();

    @Query(Select k from KeyEntity k where companyid = :companyid)    
    public KeyEntity getKeyByCompanyid(@Param("companyid") Integer companyid);
 }
```

Comment: Why not just use the inherited findById() method?

Comment: I dont know how to @Ulfa Hartina  wrote column name in entity , if this column property name is id ,he is able to use findById() Method.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Spring Data JPA. Your repository interface inherits various methods from the extended `JpaRepository` interface. That is the whole point of it.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html

There is then no read to write a query method:

```
@RestController
public class myController{

    @RequestMapping(path="/getkey/{company_id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public KeyEntity getKey(@PathVariable("company_id") int companyId) {

        return gkrepo.findById(companyId); //inherited method
    }

}
```

Furthermore, if you enable Spring Data JPA's web extension then there is no need to call the repository at all as the Entity will be resolved automatically from the path variable:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#core.web

> The DomainClassConverter lets you use domain types in your Spring MVC
>   controller method signatures directly, so that you need not manually
>   lookup the instances through the repository

```
@RestController
public class myController{

    @RequestMapping(path="/getkey/{company_id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    KeyEntity getKey(@PathVariable KeyEntity keyEntity) {

        return keyEntity; 
    }
}
```